# How to show date time to end user depending upon their time zone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am using amazon ec2 service to host my site.My site data is populated by web api which contain one post method which has parameter **AddedDate** to make date as UTC I wrote code like

```
up.AddedDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
```

and store it in db. After retrieving date from db I convert it into local date time like

```
@DateTime.Parse((item.Addeddate).ToString()).ToLocalTime();
```

but it does not convert date time in my time zone.Is ther any need to store timezone info inn db.If suppose my client are in different time zone how should I recover from this problem.Plase help me.

Comment: You have to call `ToLocalTime` on the client e. g. JavaScript

Comment: I already did it. In front end I get value in model so **item.Addeddate.ToString().ToLocalTime() ** oh you want to say that this code also run on server and I need to convert it on client machine.Good I will try it.